# Displaying one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables
1. employees
2. contacts

```
 employees
 id    name
  1    Smith
  2    Ken
  3    Tim

 contacts
  id         phone          emp_id
   1         431-1234          1
   2         431-5678          1
   3         431-3421          2
```

In employees table id is primary key and in contacts table emp_id is foreign key of employees table

output needed is,

```
 Name       Contacts
 Smith      431-1234, 431-5678
```

When i tried,

```
 SELECT * FROM employees e, contacts c WHERE e.id=emp_id
```

I get repeating names.

```
 $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees e, contacts c WHERE e.id=emp_id");
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    echo $r['name'] .' '. $r['phone'];
 }
```

Comment: This is correct, you've formulated the product of both tables. What is your programming question then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` in combination with `group_concat`:

```
select e.name, group_concat(c.phone separator ', ') phone
from employees e inner join contacts c on e.id = c.emp_id 
group by e.id
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use this query:

```
select a.name,group_concat(b.phone separator ', ') as contacts
from employees a join contacts b
on a.id = b.emp_id
```

This because you only want to show 2 columns, and what you're doing now is showing "all"

Comment: OP is looking for a comma-separated string concatenation of phone

Comment: Sure, but what I understand is that he want to display only 2 columns including the separator...anyway, I edit the post